# Using textbox to update another text box in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, dlookup

I am trying to update a textbox#2 based on the value in Textbox#1.
The value in the textbox#1 is taken from from a string using " Mid([ScantheCode],1,10)" from ScantheCode box. I have tried couple of things but I am getting #error or #name.

I am using

=(DLookUp("ProductName","List","ProductN=" & [Textbox#1] & "'"))

Please help me find the solution for it.

Thank you,
regards,
Rohan

Answer (score 0):

ProductN is probably *text*, so try inserting the missing quote:

```
=DLookUp("ProductName","List","ProductN = '" & [Textbox#1] & "'")
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, Thank you for the help. It is working. But if I use this with afterupdate or onchange. It does not work any idea on this?

Comment: You may need to requery the textbox.